# How can i converts the COCO dataset into a set of TFRecords on Google cloud TPU

Tags: google-cloud-tpu

I am trying to prepare the COCO dataset. 
on link https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/tutorials/retinanet#prepare_the_coco_dataset
it is given 
"The tpu/tools/datasets/download_and_preprocess_coco.sh script converts the COCO dataset into a set of TFRecords that the training application expects"

When i try it i am getting 
-bash: tpu/tools/datasets/download_and_preprocess_coco.sh: No such file or directory

How can i solve it

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you are using one of the `ml-images` provided by Google Cloud, that script should reside in the `/usr/share/tpu/` directory, which is a copy of the github repository at https://github.com/tensorflow/tpu.

I ran the following command and got the following result on a brand-new instance created from the 1.12 image.

```
$ file /usr/share/tpu/tools/datasets/download_and_preprocess_coco.sh 
/usr/share/tpu/tools/datasets/download_and_preprocess_coco.sh: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
```

Please let me know if this works, or if you run into any further difficulties.